# parse file with space delimitter

Tags: string, visual-studio-2010, perl, parsing

I have a file with chinese content that I need to parse. Each post has some weird delimitter between fields and I am trying to isolate the fields but cannot recognize the delimitter.

```
Dim stringSplitter() as string = {" "}
Try
  sampleResults = entry.Split(stringSplitter,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

.....
```

A sample of the post content;

```
108087006686338t.qq.com/GAOCHUANG8899homeGAOCHUANG8899homehttp://t.qq.com/p/t/1080870066863382012-03-22 04:49:46
```

The separator starts after the first set of digits 108087006686338 DELIMITTER   t.qq.com/GAOCHUANG8899home . I initially thought I could split it using json but this is definitely not json format.

Sorry when I post the original the delimitters disappear when making this post. The delimitter looks like a rectangular block

EDIT:

Ok using the hex editor I identified the character hex value as 01 and it looks like a period but the period has a value of 2E. Does this mean anything to anyone?

EDIT:

Reproducing the question: can I split a string based on a hex value. If the value is "01" then how would I split the string based on that value.

EDIT:

final answer:`

```
Dim hvalue as Char = Char(1)
Dim stringSplitter() as string = {hvalue}
```

Comment: There is no character between the `6338` and the `t.qq.com` in the sample content. Are you sure the data is delimited? Maybe the fields are based on position.

Comment: sorry guys; is there anyway to show the original without pasting. I tried using the space character in my code but it splits the string at the datetime

Comment: Format it as code. It will keep spaces.

Comment: id does not save the spaces; when I view the text file or past the content in I see that delimitter but after saving the post; its gone.

Comment: You can use a hex editor to see what the delimiter is.

Comment: there is a space between the fields and it cannot be based on position because one of the fields is a text field which will be different for each post unless there is a max count which I do not know

Comment: Hex editors shows period also for characters that cannot be printed and chr(01) is one of them. So it is not real period/dot character.

Comment: Hey jonathan M, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have input `$input` and delimitter with ascii code of `01`.

**Perl:**

```
my $input = ...
my @output = split(chr(01), $input);
print "$_\t" for @output; # print all items
```

The code above will split your `$input` into `@output` array, so then you can access items via

```
$output[0] # first item
$output[1] # second item
...
$#output + 1 # number of items
```

**Visual-Studio-2010**:

```
Dim hvalue as Char = Char(1)
Dim stringSplitter() as string = {hvalue}
```